# Removing Apple ID from my phone

Tags: iphone

I've just upgraded my phone and am giving my son my old one how do I remove my Apple ID from the old phone and will it affect my new phone

Comment: see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351 - essentially, wipe it & set up fresh with a new personal Apple ID. Use [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) if you want apps/music etc to be available to the new ID.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these 6 shocking steps to prepare your iPhone for another user:

## - [What to do before selling or giving away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351)

Comment: I thought we closed link only answers

Comment: You could vote to close @Mark - it's not a link only answer if there are words explaining the link. Also, know the rules well so you can know how to break them properly... :-)